# Ubuntu 18.04 Display Port Disconnected

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I have GTX 1060 and integrated Intel graphics card.

I was using 17.10 without any issues however after installing 18.10, I started to have some issue regarding to my card;

I have 3 ports; 2 of them belongs to Nvidia, one belongs to Intel.

If I don't add anything to GRUB, then only Intel port works, if I add `nomodeset` or `nomodeset grub_gfxmode=vesa` to Grub, only Nvidia works (2 screens).

3rd screen (also laptop's screen) shows `/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, xxxx/xxxx files, xxxxx/xxxx blocks`

When I run `xrandr` I get the following;

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 6000 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected primary 3440x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x 
axis y axis) 800mm x 335mm
   3440x1440     59.97*+  49.99    29.99  
   2560x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-0 connected 2560x1440+3440+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y 
axis) 553mm x 311mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1200x960      59.90  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Unfortunately `xrandr --addmode DP-1 1920x1080` didn't work either;

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  35
Current serial number in output stream:  36
```

Driver info `$ lshw -c video`

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:146 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
*-display UNCLAIMED
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:a0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Are there any known fixes around this issue? Perhaps I'm doing something wrong but at this point I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why I haven't thought of this before, however the solution was simple.

I just had to modify my grub and add `modeset=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and now can use all 3 ports as I used to (almost but still)

It looks like there is a small glitch though. After login, about a second screens go black. However overall the speed of OS is not effected.

Comment: No idea what this does, but it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @axel22 if I'm not mistaken this enables the display mode for display controller.